# How do I retrive firebase data in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I am trying to get a list of data from a firebase database and display it as a list in my flutter app, at the moment I cannot get the data to appear, on the UI.When I try and print the list it does not contain any values when it should show the names I have entered in the database.

This is the database that I am trying to retrieve:

[image: This is the database that I am trying to retrieve:]

This is the code that I have implemented for my UI, any ideas on what is the issue here?

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'SignInSuccessPage.dart';

class SignInPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SignInPageState createState() => SignInPageState();
}

class SignInPageState extends State<SignInPage> {
  List<Volunteer> volunteers;
  Volunteer volunteer;
  DatabaseReference volunteerRef;


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    volunteers = new List();
    volunteer = Volunteer("","", "");
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance; /
    volunteerRef = database.reference().child('volunteerapp-cec4f');
    volunteerRef.onChildAdded.listen(_onEntryAdded);
    volunteerRef.onChildChanged.listen(_onEntryChanged);

  }

  _onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      volunteers.add(Volunteer.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }

  _onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    var old = volunteers.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.key == event.snapshot.key;
    });
    setState(() {
      volunteers[volunteers.indexOf(old)] = Volunteer.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('List of Names'),
      ),
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: volunteerRef,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: Text(volunteers[index].firstName),
                  subtitle: Text(volunteers[index].lastName),

                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

//the volunteer class which contains all the info about each volunteer object and links to firebase
class Volunteer {
  String key;
  String firstName;
  String lastName;

  Volunteer(this.key, this.firstName, this.lastName);

  Volunteer.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        firstName = snapshot.value["firstName"],
        lastName = snapshot.value["lastName"];

  toJson() {
    return {
      "key": key,
      "firstName": firstName,
      "lastName": lastName,
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to include the name of your project as a `child` call, it's already in the base reference.

So:

```
volunteerRef = database.reference();
```